# Basis of a space of upper triangular matrices with trace 0

Tags: matrices

What would a basis of a space of $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices with trace 0 be? Is it trivial?

Comment: A matrix does not have a basis; only a vector space has a basis. What do you really mean?

Comment: A vector space with all upper triangual matrices with trace 0.

Comment: Ben, please edit your question so it says what you mean for it to say. People shouldn't have to go through the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
 trace A=0 then $\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}=0 $then we have $a_{nn=}-a_{11}-...-a_{n-1 n-1}$
 $$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
     a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
     0 & a_{22} & a_2^2 & \cdots & a_2^n \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (-a_{11}-...-a_{n-1 n-1})    
     \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\pmatrix{
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\color{white}\circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\bullet&\bullet\\
\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ&\color{white}\circ\\
}$$

$B=\{E_{ij}:i\lt j\}$$\cup$$\{E_{ii}:i=1,2,..,n-1\}$

clearly $B$ is basis for an upper triangular matrix with trace 0 because $B$ generate it and $B$ is linear independent